# Heroku pip cannot find my recently published package in pypi

Tags: python, heroku, pypi

I recently uploaded my [Python package](https://pypi.org/project/lgp/) to PyPI. I also developed a web app depending on that package. I want to deploy my web app to Heroku. However, Heroku cannot find my package using pip.

It throws

```
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement lgp==0.0.2 (from versions: none)    
ERROR: No matching distribution found for lgp==0.0.2
```

I tried `pip install my package` on my local machine and it works fine. What's the possible reason for the failure on Heroku?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The error you cited says that the package is there, but there is no version of that package supported by the current runtime. For example, if the package requires Python 3.8 and you're running any lower version, you'll get exactly this error.

Comment: What Heroku runtime are you using? Your package requires `Python >=3.7`.

Comment: @DustinIngram Thank you, I was using default runtime. After specifying python-3.7.2 in runtime.txt, my problem is solved.

Comment: Glad to hear it! I've added this as an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your package requires `Python >=3.7`, make sure you are using a runtime with Python 3.7 or greater in it.